# Unable to run shell script in terminal

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I had previously been able to run shell script in my terminal by making it executable by:

```
sudo chmod a+x /path/to/script
```

The running it with

```
/path/to/script/./scriptToRun.sh
```

Here is the output: 
       File: dir,      Node: Top       This is the top of the INFO tree

```
  This (the Directory node) gives a menu of major topics.
  Typing "q" exits, "?" lists all Info commands, "d" returns here,
  "h" gives a primer for first-timers,
  "mEmacs<Return>" visits the Emacs manual, etc.

  In Emacs, you can click mouse button 2 on a menu item or cross reference
  to select it.

* Menu:

Texinfo documentation system
* Info: (info).                 How to use the documentation browsing system.
* Texinfo: (texinfo).           The GNU documentation format.
* info stand-alone: (info-stnd).           Read Info documents without Emacs.
* infokey: (info-stnd)In
```

Now it opens emacs and I cant seem to get it just run the script anymore.

The files have the shebang i.e `#!/bin/bash -e`

Would appreciate it if anyone had a fix for this.

Comment: It should make the script executable, not run it. Have you aliased `sudo`? Have you created a new script called `sudo` or `chmod`?

Comment: sorry I meant executable will edit question

Comment: If you ran the above commands you'd actually have made the containing directory executable, not the script itself, so you may want to `chmod a+x` the script. If that's not it, list the contents of the script for us to look at, in particular the `#!` line at the top.

Comment: It looks `info` command is executed from within the `scriptToRun.sh` script.

Comment: Found the error. Was running the script from the wrong folder and missing some imports/ dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$ cd /path/to/script && ./myscript.sh
```

If it doesn't work run this command as superuser